# The cyrillic encoding issue in play framework

Tags: mysql, playframework, character-encoding, playframework-2.3

In the **local** environment everything with encoding is ok, but when i make dist and run my app on the server (ubuntu) and do POST, cyryllic characters of json in the request body turn in └я▀п╡я└п╟я▀я└' (**as it turned out it's only the terminal issues**) in controllers:

```
def editUser = SecuredAction(WithRole(ADMIN)).async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
  log.debug(request.body) // here I have └я▀п╡я└п╟я▀я└' instead of cyrillic characters
```

I checked request headers:

```
Accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:192
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Maybe some of you encountered with that. Thx!

Comment: Can you check what are the exact **bytes** in the log?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how I can print raw request in bytes. M.b. you can tell me?

Comment: Open the log file with a hex editor and copy the hex data here. Also, what terminal emulator are you using to connect to the server? Is it set to KOI-R?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in mysql, here the answer:

I added *useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8:*

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

but it didn't help. So I added to my.etc on the server:

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
```

OK!